# Passing Data from UI layer to Business

Tags: c#, winforms, abstraction

```
class MyProjectBusiness
{
  // Interaction (read Write)) with DB
}


class MyProjectUI
{
 // this class interacts with Business Logic
}


class MyProjectUIControls
{
 // These are just User controls consumed by UI, No Interaction to Business layer
}
```

Generally I raise events from UIControls. UI Class handles those events and creates Business Classes (or populate values in Business Classes)

First, I wanted to ask is this the correct way of abstracting different layers in Software ?

Now My actual problem is - there is big class (having around 40 Properties) which has to pass data from UIControls to Business Logic, What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map properties from UI Classes to Business Classes. A good walk-through of this is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper)